# WP7 (Windows phone 7) Lock phone orientation in XAML or C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, orientation

Is it possible to manualy lock the phone orientation in Windows phone 7 ?
Because I'm using the accelerometer to handle buttons' rotation with a fixed UI.

I've tried that :

In the XAML

```
SupportedOrientations="Landscape" Orientation="LandscapeLeft"
OrientationChanged="PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged"
```

And in the code behind :

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Orientation locking
    //Do nothing
}
```

But the UI is still shifting between *landscape left* and *landscape right*...

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to prevent the shifting between LandscapeLeft and LandScapeRight. This is by design.

As a work around, you can manually rotate/transform your UIElements in the OnOrientationChanged so that the user doesn't see a difference.
I've used this technique to keep a "background" image from appearing to rotate regardless of orientation but then having a separate control which appears like a popup but which does respond to orientation changes show on top of the image.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I found a solution by overriding **OnOrientationChanged** method. It works for me. That do not affect system tray and application menu, but page stay in the selected orientation.

```
protected override void OnOrientationChanged(OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft)
        base.OnOrientationChanged(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this `this.SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.Portrait;` after `InitializeComponent();` in `MainPage()` constructor to lock the orientation in Portrait mode. It works fine for me.