# Disable orientation change when user want to

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to give to **users** my app an options that they can lock/disable orientation screen.
How can I do that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990148/wp7-windows-phone-7-lock-phone-orientation-in-xaml-or-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prevent the rotation. But you can try use this: 
http://pagerotationwp.codeplex.com/

see also
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-wptips/auto-rotate-of-the-screen/d61a7b68-6941-41f9-a4f3-375e25669032?msgId=2ace87af-b04f-405e-b949-f85f861af740

Regards