# disable orientation change for a single page wpf

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, screen-orientation

I've google it and search it on many forums but I'm surprise that they're no clear and simple solution for this: How to disable the orientation changes in a single page?

I'm developing an universal App but for now I'm just wondering how to do it in the Windows Phone Application.

Thank's for future answers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ??

add this this.SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.Portrait; after InitializeComponent(); in MainPage() constructor to lock the orientation in Portrait mode. It works fine for me.

Source ans : 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990148/wp7-windows-phone-7-lock-phone-orientation-in-xaml-or-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing it from your `XAML`?

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage   
x:Class="OrientationWp8._0.MainPage"   
.............   
SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" Orientation="Portrait"  
OrientationChanged="PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged">
```

Sample: [Page orientations](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WindowsPhone-80-vs-940c2b78)

Or else you can try it programmatically too as mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207002%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).